# Trouble Checking A List

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

Well, it seems I'm re-approaching this problem. What I'm experiencing is, I guess you could say when I "despawn" a monster (the player has killed it), and "respawn" it, it adds all the moves to the list all over again. For example:

Monster A has 2 moves in his list: Scratch & Growl... Monster A dies... Monster A respawns... Monster A now has 4 moves in his list: Scratch & Growl...AND...Scratch & Growl...

Here's my code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

 public class MonsterMoves : MonoBehaviour {

 public List<BaseMove> moves;
 public int level;
 public Scratch scratch = new Scratch();
 public Growl growl = new Growl();
 public FireBall fireball = new FireBall();
 public PowerUp powerup = new PowerUp();

 void Start(){
     moves = gameObject.GetComponent<Monster>().monstersMoves;
     level = gameObject.GetComponent<Monster>().level;
 }

 void Update(){
     level = gameObject.GetComponent<Monster>().level;
     SetupMoves(level);
 }

 private void SetupMoves(int level){
     if(level >= 1 && !moves.Contains(scratch)){
         moves.Add(scratch);
     }
     if(level >= 1 && !moves.Contains(growl)){
         moves.Add(growl);
     }
     if(level >= 7 && !moves.Contains(fireball)){
         moves.Add(fireball);
     }
     if(level >= 10 && !moves.Contains(powerup)){
         moves.Add(powerup);
     }
```

Any ideas on what I'm over-looking?

To answer some comments:

When the monster dies it's script (just called Monster) calls this:

```
public void SetDead(){
    isAlive = false;
    timeOfDeath = Time.time;

    ReSpawner.deadMonster.Add(this);

    this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

This handles "despawning" the monster, without actually destroying it. Then there's THIS script which handles the respawning:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ReSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

public float spawnDistance = 50.0f;
public float minSpawnDensity = 6f;
public float minSpawnDistance = 20f;
public int respawnDelay = 10;
public static List<Monster> deadMonster = new List<Monster>();

private Vector3 spawnPoint;
private Vector3 lastSpawnPoint = Vector3.zero;

void Update(){
    for(var i = 0; i < deadMonster.Count; i++){
        Monster monster = deadMonster [i];

        float time = Time.time - monster.timeOfDeath;

        if(time > respawnDelay)
        {
            monster.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            monster.isAlive = true;
            monster.gameObject.rigidbody.WakeUp();
            monster.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;
            monster.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MonsterAI>().enabled = true;
            spawnPoint = new Vector3(Random.Range(0, 2000), Random.Range(0, 2000), Random.Range(0, 2000));
            spawnPoint.y = TerrainHeight(spawnPoint);
            if(!IsInvalidSpawnPoint(spawnPoint, lastSpawnPoint)){
                NavMeshHit closestHit;
                if(NavMesh.SamplePosition(spawnPoint, out closestHit, 500, 1)){
                    spawnPoint = closestHit.position;
                }else{
                    Debug.Log("...");
                }
                monster.gameObject.transform.position = spawnPoint;
                monster.SetupMonster();
                deadMonster.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}

private bool IsInvalidSpawnPoint(Vector3 spawnPoint,Vector3 lastSpawnPoint){
    if(spawnPoint.y == Mathf.Infinity || (spawnPoint - lastSpawnPoint).magnitude <= minSpawnDensity){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

private float TerrainHeight(Vector3 spawnPoint){
    Ray rayUp = new Ray(spawnPoint, Vector3.up);
    Ray rayDown = new Ray(spawnPoint, Vector3.down);
    RaycastHit hitPoint;
    if(Physics.Raycast(rayUp, out hitPoint, Mathf.Infinity)){
        return hitPoint.point.y;
    }
    else if(Physics.Raycast(rayDown, out hitPoint, Mathf.Infinity)){
        return hitPoint.point.y;
    }else{
        return Mathf.Infinity;
    }
}
```

}

I'm hesitant to post the ENTIRE "Monster" script because it's quite extensive.

SO I'VE MADE SOME CHANGES. Now I call the function whenever the monster is first created, and if/when it levels up. Here's the new script for the MonsterMoves...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class Moves : MonoBehaviour {

public List<Move> moves;
public List<Move> movesToLearn = new List<Move>();

void Start(){
    moves = gameObject.GetComponent<Monster>().monstersMoves;
}

public void AddMoves(int level, List<Move> moves){
    foreach(Move move in movesToLearn){
        if(level >= move.levelLearned){
            if(!moves.Contains(move)){
                moves.Add(move);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

I call this function in the script that handles all of the properties of the monster. If the list of Moves already has the move in it, I don't want to add it again. However, it's still not working properly. It's STILL adding the move to the list, even if it's already in there.

Comment: What is called when it is killed, and what is called when it is brought back. Some code from another  class might be helpful in figuring out what it is doing.

Comment: BTW could you use a set of moves instead of a list?

Comment: @9000 I'm not quite sure what you mean by this. Are you suggesting I hard-code it into the Monster class? If so that won't work, because the Monster class is just a generic for all monsters, but not all monsters have the same attacks.

Comment: 9000 is suggesting List<BaseMove> moves  be Set<BaseMove> moves, which is a good suggestion, but is not what is causing the issue

Comment: @DavidRosenIII: My idea was that `List<BaseMove>` could be a `Set<BaseMove>`, so that adding the same move twice does not result in duplicates. If various parts of your code update the move list, and it's hard to coordinate the additions, you could save on constant checking.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that would do it, but it could be one of the methods called by ReSpawner.Update(). My guess just from reading the names is that you may have put something inside of the method Monster.SetupMonster()

Comment: I suggest that you create a [minimal, self-contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will either help you find the problem yourself or help us see the problem.

Comment: I've made another adjustment and added it to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Remove monster A from the list before you respawn it!

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by this. Monster A isn't in a list. Monster A HAS a list of BaseMoves. (Each move derrives from BaseMove).

Comment: This is likely not the problem, but it gets at a good question, how are you 'despawning' Monster A?

Comment: I don't think so. Just don't add them twice. There is no reason to clear the list just to refill it, that is inefficient.

Comment: When and where are you suggesting I reset the list? ...and why?